Как присвоить одинаковые значения в поля разных таблиц SQL Server?
Используется C# ASP.NET, SQLServer (SSMS)
Есть две таблицы: company и users.
В таблице company есть столбцы id - guid, bigBoss - guid. companyName - varchar и прочие
В таблице users есть столбцы id - guid, isBoss - bit, companyId - guid и прочие.
При регистрации пользователь указывает компанию в которой он работает (companyName) и указывает является ли он директором (isBoss). Если такая компания существует в таблице company, то ее id должен присваиваться пользователю в столбце companyId. Если такой компании не существует, то она создается в таблице и ее id также присваивается пользователю.
Помимо того, если пользователь директор (isBoss) компании, то его id присваивается в столбец bigBoss в таблице company
Вопрос: как это реализовать? В бэкенде буквально день, идей нет и мыслей нет.

Ну прямо распишите по шагам каждый сценарий. Только многое будет зависеть от того, как вы общаетесь с SQL - через ORM типа Entity Framework или через вызов stored procedure. Во втором случае возможно вся логика будет на SQL в процедуре. А в первом нужно придерживаться стиля работы с БД считал->изменил->записал.

То есть, сценарии можно прописать в самом бэкенд коде?

Вы сначала просто словами распишите, какие мелкие действия нужно делать в каких случаях. По шагам каждый кейс. Например: "Если такая компания существует в таблице company" - это что? Ищем в таблице company, есть ли там запись с указанными companyName и isBoss. Нашли? Пишем шаги, которые делаем в этом случае. Не нашли? Пишем другие шаги. И вот так всё по мелким шагам расписать. Сначала словами, через дискретные конкретные действия, каждое из которых можно выполнить отдельным запросом к БД. А дальше собираем это в одну процедуру. Но где и какая это будет процедура - зависит, см. выше.

Понял, спасибо!

Просто вставляй компанию. Если она есть, будет ошибка дублирования, её игнорируешь. А теперь запрашиваешь компанию, и она в таблице гарантированно имеется. То есть ничего проверять не надо.
